# How do I pass dynamic actions to AWS Glue trigger resource in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-glue

I'm trying to create a trigger in Terraform that will run a glue job with several different sets of parameters. One of those parameters is based on an arbitrary number of json dictionaries.

The problem is when I try to do this with a dynamic block for the actions in the trigger I get the following error:

> Error: Insufficient actions blocks
> At least 1 "actions" blocks are required.

Presumably, because the aws_glue_trigger resource requires there to be an actions block and making this dynamic prevents the plan from recognising it as such?
This is what my resource block looks like:

```
resource "aws_glue_trigger" "api_ingestion" {
  name     = "some trigger"
  enabled  = local.is_live_environment

  dynamic "actions" {
    for_each = fileset(path.module, "../queries/*.json")
    content {
      job_name = module.api_ingestion_job.job_name
      arguments = {
        "--json"      = file(actions.value)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does `fileset(path.module, "../queries/*.json")` return empty result?

Comment: well, that was foolish. A wood for the trees moment - thank you